Https request redirect to http (301) cause cors error
My website, hosted on EC2 and powered by Nginx, utilizes a .NET WebAPI. Occasionally, when the front-end calls the API from a different domain (same server), it functions correctly. However, at other times, I encounter a 301 redirect to HTTP instead of the original HTTPS call, resulting in CORS errors. Can anyone provide guidance on resolving this issue? Below are the configurations for Nginx and the WebAPI startup code.
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name web.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   server_name web.com;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;  
  
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://11.11.11.11:8888;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      
      }    
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name webapi.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   server_name webapi.com;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/apikey.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/apicert.pem;
  
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://11.11.11.11:6868;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
   }    
}

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer",
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Description = "JWT Authorization",
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
            Scheme = "Bearer"
        });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" }
            },
            new string[] { }
        }
    });
});


// Authentication JWT
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            RoleClaimType = "role",
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddCors();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddLogging(o =>
{
    o.AddConsole();
    o.AddDebug();
});

builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
builder.Services.Configure<GoogleCalendarSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(GoogleCalendarSettings)));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IGoogleCalendarSettings>(s => s.GetRequiredService<IOptions<GoogleCalendarSettings>>().Value);

builder.Services.AddApplication();

builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

var scopeFactory = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();

scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMailReminderService>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
});
app.MapControllers();

app.UseInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

app.Run();


The order of your middleware is incorrect; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order
